# XML Banner Rotator in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cc

XML Code file `Slider.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<slide DELAY="2">
    <image URL="SliderImages/1.jpg" links="http://www.link1.com" />
    <image URL="SliderImages/2.jpg" links="http://www.link2.com" />
</slide>
```

Here is my actionScript3 Code.

```
function Complete(e:Event):void {
    var _xml:XML=new XML(e.target.data);
    _loader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, Complete);
    _loader=null;
    _delay=_xml.@DELAY;
    _images=_xml.image;
    _total=_images.length();
    LoadImages();
}

function LoadImages():void {
    for (var i:int = 0; i < _total; i++) {
        var _url:String=_images[i].@URL;
        _linked=_images[i].@links;
        var _loader:Loader = new Loader();
        _loader.load(new URLRequest(_url));
        my_link.push(_linked);
        _loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, ImageLoaded);
        _loaders.push(_loader);

        _loader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage);
    }
}

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage(event:MouseEvent):void { 
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest(_linked)); 
}
```

My code is working fine, but the Hyper link is not working correctly.

How can I add hyper link in the loop so `navigateToURL` user starts to work?

Comment: The **_linked** variable is all alone and cannot possibly contain all the links at once. It holds only the last one assigned. You should think in OOP way: create a component that takes the initialization data (image URL and link, or the whole XML node, whatever) then load the image and act like a button to navigate to the link on click. Then, you create as many instances of that component as your whole XML dictates, passing each it's own node. Thus you'll get a bunch of **different** buttons each holding it's own image and it's own link.

Comment: Here is all code. But how to add link can some one help to see this code  http://www.codescratcher.com/flash/simple-xml-banner-rotator-flash/

Comment: That's not how it is going to work. As I said above, you need to learn OOP principles and component approach to coding first.

Comment: i started to learn OOP objected oriented principles and component approach but any one answer the code for my question he will be appreciate and thank